# Directives SUDDENLY not recognized in @Component

Tags: angular, components, webstorm

For some reason, the `directives` property for the `@component` metadata is not recognized, red underlined..

[image]

Resulting my Components cannot be loaded, browser's console screaming :

`'account-transactions' is not a known element:`

Would really appreciate any help, can't seem to be able to figure out what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you updated to RC.6

`directives` and `pipes` were deprecated in RC.5 and removed in RC.6

Use instead `declarations` in `@NgModule()`

Comment: I did remove node_modules and npm installed again but how come i suddenly in RC6? my `package.json` remained unchanged, using RC6 you now declare all the Components in the `app.module` and not in each Component that uses the specific Components? (hope my sentence made sense)

Comment: I guess you don't have a fix version constraint but one that allows a version range. You need to create modules and assign directives, components, and pipes to **exactly one** `NgModule` each. If you want to use one of these in another `NgModule` add the module to the `@NgModule({imports: [...]` })`

Comment: you were absolutely right! , i had `^` on each of my `@angular/XXXX` dependencies withing the package.json, removing it solved it and now `directives` is recognized.

Comment: Out of the scope of this question, should i use `declarations` and leave the `directives` aside?

Comment: Definitely. `directives` are already gone as you have discovered.

Comment: So when declaring the used components in the `declarations` of the `ngModule`, there's no needin any declarations withing the specific using component of the declared components?

Comment: No, what you add to declarations is available everywhere inside this module. If you add this module to `imports` of another module, everything listed under `exports` in the first module will be available everywhere in the importing module.

Comment: Thank you very much sir ! :)